# How can I add alpha values to variables in css?

Tags: css

How can I add alpha values to variables in css?

Like this.

```
color: var(--color-alt) + 80
```

So for example if I set a color like `#32a6a8` as --color-alt & then I also want to have a transparency of 50% for that color applied (alpha code for 50% transparency is 80 - that's why its there `var(--color-alt) + 80`).

The variable is required since this is an angular app & it needs to set the color values dynamically with colors having transparency of 50%.

So is there a way to do this is native css?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55330103/8620333

Comment: Can I do this with hex color codes?

Comment: No its not working out!

Comment: it will be text color or background color? there is no generic solution for what you want but workarounds based on your case

Comment: It is for this: box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--color-alt)

Comment: so share your full code then, it can be achieved with box-shadow

Comment: There are no other dependencies. If I';m about to show you full code I will have to upload the whole app. That' too heavy!!!

Comment: not *full code* of your app.Only the needed code to show your use case. to show how your are using box-shadow doesn't need you to upload your entire app

Answer (score 1):

You can use other color system. Like this `color: rgba(var(--color), var(--alpha));`

Comment: Or Is there a way to convert hex to rgba in css?

Comment: You only can convert color by js. or you can try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929458/sass-converting-hex-to-rgba-for-background-opacity

Comment: Hex colors do not have an alpha channel for transparency , hsla() or rgba() do. You need to use one of them. More details of the use you wanna do, could open other choices. Blend-mode/opacity?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: hex-colours do have an alpha channel: `#RRGGBBAA` (or `#RGBA`): [CSS Tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/](https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/).

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica it actually seems to be much more supported nowdays than i thought, however, it is not cpmpatible with the use of var() nor calc()  :(